# how to change GWT compile output path in Eclipse 4.6

Tags: gwt

I use eclipse 4.6 to compile my gwt project.

The output path is `target/se-monitor-1.0-SHAPSHOT/`.

I want to change the path to `src/main/webapp`.

I adopt  change run `configurations --> GWT compiler --->arguments---> working directory`, but the result is `src/main/webapp/war`.
There is a war catalog.
How can I delete the war catalog?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about GWT Eclipse plugin.

If so, then I do this by

- editing the .launch configuration
- going to the Arguments tab
- manually entering extra argument `-war <your_desired_location>`

I don't know if Eclipse lets you edit this in any other way. It might, but I don't know.

Comment: Thanks ,I have solved it by your answer.  Add -war 
 D:\ennwifiworkspace\se-monitor\src\main\webapp\